# Express JS Stream not working behind Reverse Proxy

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a problem where i try to stream a response from my API Server to the requester (in my case another backend). It handles a msauth login. The first response is the url for the login and the second response is the user that finished logging in with that url.

this is my controller that handles the login Request

oauth.controller.ts

```
public msalLogin = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction): Promise<void> => {
    try {
      // create a new event emitter instance for this session
      const identifier: string = req.sessionID;
      const oAuthUrl: string = await this.oAuthService.msalLogin(identifier);

      const acceptStreamHeader = req.get('X-Accept-Response-Stream');
      if (acceptStreamHeader !== 'true') {
        // Return a 400 Bad Request response if X-Accept-Response-Stream header is not set
        res.status(400).send('X-Accept-Response-Stream header is required for this request \n Please use a stream to handle this request');
      }

      // Set the Transfer-Encoding header to 'chunked'
      res.setHeader('Transfer-Encoding', 'chunked');
      // res.set('Transfer-Encoding', 'chunked');
      res.set('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream');
      // Set a custom header to indicate that the client wants to receive the response as a stream
      res.set('X-Accept-Response-Stream', 'true');

      // First, send a link in the response
      res.write(JSON.stringify({ loginUrl: oAuthUrl }));

      const handleLoginFinishEvent = (foundUser: AuthenticationResult) => {
        res.write(JSON.stringify(foundUser));
        res.end();
      }

      const eventName = identifier+'-loginFinished';
      this.eventEmitter.once(eventName, handleLoginFinishEvent);

      //nach 5 minuten event entfernen!
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.eventEmitter.removeListener(eventName, handleLoginFinishEvent);
        res.status(705);
        res.write(JSON.stringify({error: "Login has been aborted after being idle for 5 minutes"}))
        res.end();
      }, 1000 * 60 * 5)

    } catch (error) {
      next(error);
    }
  };
```

And yes, the rest of my routes work behind the nginx proxy... except for this one

it all works perfectly on localhost and dev environment. But it stops working as soon as i put it behind our nginx reverse proxy.

When it is behind the reverse proxy it seems like its not handling it as a stream and waiting till the response completely finishes (which it never doese because the requester never gets the link to login)

I tried to google this problem but nothing i found was similar to my problem...
Is there any way to fix this? Can i tell the nginx reverse proxy to also use streams?

**EDIT:** calling the api with insomnia (REST Client) on localhost -> then it runs forever... but if i call if to the prod domain it throws me this error: "Error: Stream error in the HTTP/2 framing layer"

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

So i fixed it myself. The problem was: the reverse proxy tries to transform my api response to HTTP/2 but somehow transforming a stream into HTTP/2 doesnt work properly. So i requested it with a special package from my application backend which requests it as http2 by default. The npm package is called https://www.npmjs.com/package/fetch-h2